# Is a landlord attempting to collect on a debt covered by the Dodd-Frank Act

Tags: landlord, debt

If a landlord alleges that a former tenant owes money for damages caused to the house during the tenancy, are the landlord's actions while attempting to collect the alleged debt covered by the Dodd-Frank act?

I ask because, in the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau's [bulletin](http://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/201307_cfpb_bulletin_unfair-deceptive-abusive-practices.pdf) on the act, says the act covers original creditors, but it refers to the debtor as the "consumer".  I am not sure whether this act then only covers consumer debt (i.e. store purchases etc.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am a landlord and not an attorney. For that reason,  will answer this question from that perspective.

The Dodd Frank Act covers "collections" as primarily in a collections agency. If can cover a corporation collecting debts of course. It has nothing to do with a landlords ability to obtain a judgement or collect a debt which is covered by your states Tenant Landlord Act (or something similar).

The landlord has the right to file a complaint against anyone who has not paid rent, caused damage to the property, or any other loss to the landlord as a result of your action or inaction. Filing and getting a judgement is not collections as covered by the Dodd Frank Act. Once a judgement or judgements have been entered, there are several options including through the sheriffs department seizure and forfeiture depending upon your state law.

Only *if* the landlord sends your debt to a collections agency, does the Dodd Frank Act apply and, in that, only applies to how the collections agency that collects the debt and not to the landlord. It does not apply to the debt, the ability or right to collect the debt. It applies to the behavior of the collections agency seeking to collect the debt only.

For what it is worth, with so many legal options available to the landlord and not similarly afforded to consumer debt, it is unlikely that the landlord will use a collections agency. Options can include a collections attorney, the sheriffs department, direct collection by the landlord, the courts, etc. Landlords often take a loss of some sort using a collection agency and therefore avoid the option unless as a last resort. Often, if direct collection efforts fail, the landlord will either receive relief through the courts or through the sheriffs department according to state law, both of which are unavoidable and not ordinarily covered by the Dodd Frank Act. In this case, it is akin to owing the state the debt just like any other debt owed to the state. The state will have rights afforded by law such as the right to withhold privileges offered by the state such as drivers licenses, titles, tags, building permits, other licenses, etc. This may not apply equally in all states. You will have to read your states law to know what the limits of the ability of a landlord to obtain and collect a debt are.

Comment: Are you saying that there are states in which a non-governmental landlord can *use the full authority and power of the state to collect a debt or judgement*?  Can you elaborate on that?  Unless I'm misunderstanding something that would astonish me.

Comment: @feetwet Yes and no. If I were to turn over a judgement to the sheriff or constables office, as a landlord or otherwise, pay the bond to cover any collections disputes, yes the state will collect on my behalf with the full power of the state. This includes forfeiture, garnishments, seizure of private property and bank accounts, etc. A bond is about $500 so for landlords they are more interested in getting their property back without an issue, however, if you have a particularly bad tenant as I had a couple of months ago, it is a very real option I have chosen to take.

Comment: @feetwet BTW- related to this question. http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8720/is-fraudulent-activity-related-to-renting-a-residence-theft-by-deception We are swearing complaints to build a fact pattern to prosecute the person mentioned in this question. The sheriff has already collected some monies already and will be collecting on more judgments from myself and perhaps others. The police, townships, county, state, and federal, are all on this persons tail. So it will be an interesting story in the end. Cheers!!

Comment: Then why would anybody use a collections company against entities in PA?  Pretty much any non-governmental collection effort is going to cost way more than $500 *even if successful*, and private collections agencies are very restricted in the measures they can take.  If what you say is true then it sounds like once a judgement is handed to the sheriff, if the debtor doesn't leave the state, it won't be long before the government shakes every last penny out of them!  But I know there are debtors who have (somehow) evaded collections on judgments for years in PA.

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the point of the question.  I think everyone agrees that a landlord has the right to sue a tenant and to enforce their judgment in the usual ways.  The question is about collection practices.  For instance, suppose a landlord calls a tenant's employer and says "Hey, your deadbeat employee Joe Smith owes me $1,000 and won't pay."  That would be illegal for a debt collector to do under Dodd-Frank.  Is it illegal for the landlord?

Comment: @feetwet The debtor does not even have to be in the state. Mine is in another state now and was actually running from the law in another state. ;-) Much her assets are in another state, bank, income, car, etc. Your point is right about collecting. However, a judgment is required therefore you have to calculate the cost of the courts which is about $1000 in my case. My losses are about $4000 so far. So getting the state to collect is not necessarily always a path people want to go down, however, costs are always rolled into the amount collected. And it is always collected.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you read Dodd Fank, calling the employer is *not* against the law. As well state laws can regulate much the same thing. In PA, the same legal restrictions required by the state mirrors the federal law. Landlords will often NOT collect a debt on their own unless they are a large corporation. My point is that Dodd Frank does not generally apply to landlords because of the other options available and their reluctance to be in the collections business. Often, this would be handled by an attorney making legal demands then going to court for a judgment which a landlord can do.

Comment: @feetwet Here is another interesting thought. The courts require that anyone who moves with an unsatisfied judgement (issue before the court) to register their new address and phone number with the court and continue doing so until the judgement is satisfied. Anyone evicted must do this. Failure to do so is a crime. PA has issued a warrant for those who have failed and have had any other jurisdictions arrest the individual until the state is satisfied that they have accurate information and the individual can properly be served if necessary. This is not normally done, but can be.

Comment: Wow, I was always under the impression that collections from a determined scofflaw were nearly impossible.  It sounds like I may have been exceedingly ignorant!  I want to formulate a question so that you can expound these details.  (Or you might do one and self-answer?)

Comment: @feetwet It can also be difficult to collect depending upon where you are. For example, some local laws can make it almost impossible such as in Philadelphia. I sold all my properties in MD, not because collecting is difficult, but because the fees, requirements, and inspections, were too costly even with $1600 per unit. MD makes collections difficult, but allows you to take everything including the drawers the debtor is wearing. ;-) I collected $45,000 in MD as a consultant when I retired. It takes time, however, when you have labor laws behind you and the state DA, it becomes easier.

Comment: @closetnoc: If you look at page 5 of the CFPB bulletin linked in the question, there are citations to cases where courts have held that calling the employer is an unfair practice in violation of the Federal Trade Commission Act, and the footnote on page 1 seems to say that the same standards apply to Dodd-Frank.  Also, page 1 of the bulletin says that Dodd-Frank applies to the original creditor as well as to professional collectors, so the fact that the landlord is not a professional collector doesn't obviously exempt them from its terms.

Comment: @NateEldredge The question is about Dodd Frank and landlords. Landlords generally do not do their own collecting. You have to stop thinking of someone who is collecting a credit card debt. It is completely different for landlords. Mostly, landlords are in a position to make the debtor, who is smart or at least not a complete moron, WANT to pay the landlord. Why? Because all matter of hell is about to drop on their head. For example, Credit? Gone. Looking for another apartment? Forget it. Want to buy a house? Not happening. Want a new job? Think again. Rent or buy a car? You gotta be kidding?

Comment: @NateEldredge Smart tenants talk to attorneys. Smart attorneys, including ultra-liberal street attorneys, tell the tenant to settle with the landlord before going to court and go on with their life. The idea that any tenant can fight a landlord and avoid eviction, is mostly fiction that exists in certain cities. Other than these cases, any attorney will not touch a tenant landlord dispute unless the landlord has violated the law. Even then, all landlords win so most attorneys do not advise fighting a landlord and recommend simply settling and avoid an eviction and judgment on their record.

Comment: @NateEldredge Unrelated to this question, I had to research and read the federal and state law to know what hours I can call someone who owed me money. This was not a collections call, but still. I was concerned about the times which are 8am to 9pm. Okay. I was surprised to see that it is not against the law to call someone at work. However, is it advisable? Of course not. The legal definition within the law is (paraphrasing here) knowing it causes an embarrassment or jeopardizes the debtors job. It is still not against the law to call unless asked not to for a valid legal reason.

Comment: Yes, I see the bigger picture.  I'm trying to understand a specific technical point, which I think is the focus of the question.  You keep saying that landlords are "completely different" and are not subject to the Dodd-Frank requirements, but I don't understand how the law distinguishes them.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not saying that Dodd Frank may not apply, I am saying that collections for landlords is completely different. It is not calling and asking for the money. Landlords do not have to collect the same way that credit card companies (as an example) collect. Most landlords never speak to the debtor again. Instead, the state collects or the debtor wants your judgement lifted and sends you a check. In fact, most of the time, they want to hand you the check quickly and not waste the time waiting on the post office! Otherwise, their whole world stops.

Comment: Okay, but then I don't think the hypothetical I raised in my earlier comment has been addressed.  You're saying it's unlikely to arise in reality but I still want to know what would happen if it did.  Tenant owes money to landlord, landlord calls tenant's employer in an attempt to collect.  Is landlord subject to penalties under Dodd-Frank or similar federal laws?

Comment: @NateEldredge In otherwords, landlords do not chase a debtor, but a debtor will chase a landlord to pay the debt quickly because it is their best interest to do so. Even if the debtor is a con-man. It all catches up. Jail is always a possibility. In fact, Arkansas had (may still have) a law that allowed a tenant 10 days late on rent to be arrested. I do not like that of course. It goes over the line. Still.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes. They must obey the same laws for any collections activities they take on assuming taking on collections like any other corporation. It just does not happen though. Not in my 30 years.